# KnockOut run function on value changed

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

Got simple viewModel:

```
function viewModel() {
    enabled: ko.observable(false);
    ...
}
```

and some binding like:

```
<input data-bind="hasFocus: enabled" />
```

and i want run some function on focus, and other on focus lost( or enabled = true/false) but run when value changes.
Any help?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You could subscribe to your enabled function, such as:

```
enabled.subscribe(function(newValue) {
   if(newValue) {  // Has focus

   } else { 
       // No focus
   }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

event: { mouseover: enableDetails, mouseout: disableDetails }

Try this:

```
<input data-bind="hasFocus: enabled, event: { focus: onFocus, blur: onBlur}" />
```

if you want to monitor value change you should do it in viewmodel:

```
this.enabled.subscribe(function(newValue){
    //use newValue
});
```

Note: you have syntax error in viewmodel:

```
enabled: ko.observable(false); <--
```

Answer (score 0):

Typically, a good solution is to subscribe to your observable and handle your logic there like:

```
enabled.subscribe(function(newValue) {
    if (newValue) {
        //do something if it is true
    }
    else {
        //do something if false
    }
});
```

Comment: Literally the exact same response, but with different comments! :)