# How to call a function when a visibility binding is true?

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

for an example how to execute a javascript function when the binding is visible:true meaning BooleanIndicator() have returned true, assuming that the function called has **e** as a parameter, whereby e is an event.

```
<div data-bind="visible: shouldShowMessage">
    You will see this message only when "shouldShowMessage" holds a true value.
</div>

<div >
 Also show this div when the above div is visble

<div>
```

Comment: `data-bind` is what framework?

Comment: @epascarello is a jquery knockout binding

Comment: @Wicky Then why not make it `computed` function or have `subscribe` function

Comment: Possible duplicate of [KnockOut run function on value changed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18253206/knockout-run-function-on-value-changed)

Answer (score 0):

Binding is dependent on the data in your view model. If `BooleanIndicator()` is an observable property of your viewmodel you can create a computed function that should get called whenever the BooleanIndicator() changes

```
self.ComputedFunction = ko.computed(function() {
    if (self.BooleanIndicator()){
        //Do something - I'm visible
    } else {
        // Do something else
    }
});
```

Comment: Note, you should not answers basic question. You should search for related post and mark it as duplicate.

Comment: The answer may be the same but the question and the way ti is phrased are different.

Comment: it's just a friendly advice. Also question and the ways will always be similar never same. But it's all good. Just, self.BooleanCondition is missing ()